# How can I set the newsletter to send me more current topics?

Tags: support

As it is now, my weekly elementaryos stackexchange newsletter sends me old, even ancient, questions/topics. For example, yesterday's n-letter (May 11, 2021) included "When will elementary OS Loki be released?" and 2 other Loki-based questions.

Are there any settings I can change to get more current topics in my newsletter?